# How to obtain the position of Qt widget?

Tags: qt, animation

Here is  the code.

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation3 = new QPropertyAnimation (ui->modifyButton, "geometry");
animation3->setDuration(1000);
animation3->setStartValue(QRect(20, 120,  141, 20));
animation3->setStopValue(QRect(20, 70, 141, 20));
animation3->start();
```

I need the application to automatically determine the "Y" coordinate of  modifyButton as it is not fixed and is changing. So how can I do something like this.

```
int  y = get_y_coordinate_somehow();

animation3->setStartValue(QRect(20, y, 141, 20));start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pos()` method.

```
int y = pos().y();
```